# Find the differential equations that are satisfied by geodesics on the torus with parametrization given

Tags: differential-geometry

I have question
Find the differential equations that are satisfied by geodesics on the torus with parametrization given 
$X(u,v)=((R+rcos(u))cos(v),(R+rcos(u))sin(v),rsin(u))$?

I hope someone can solve

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential geometry of the torus is discussed in detail in [this document](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf).

The equations of geodesics are in section 4. They are:

[image]

His notation is slightly different from yours: his $a$ is your $r$ and his $c$ is your $R$. The $k$ and $l$ are constants of integration. See the paper for details.

Comment: thank you i have question when the question said find differential equation is the same find the geodesics equation thanks

Comment: The equations above **are** differential equations. A differential equation is one that contains derivatives of functions. The $u$ and $v$ with dots above them denote derivatives, so the equations are differential equations.